# Detect unadmitted tags by specifying the admitted ones in a textarea using JQuery or Javascript and if a button it's clicked remove it

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm going mad because I want to give to the user a feedback about the tags unadmitted in a textarea.

### There's a way to detect unadmitted tags in a textarea by specifying the admitted ones?

like

```
<script>
var admittedTagsArray = ['a','p','div'];

function arrayDetectUnadmittedTagsBySpecifyingTheAdmittedOnes(admittedTagsArray,textarea.val()) {
   [...]  <<  I donno know what
   return unadmittedTagsArray;
}

function buttonClickedRemoveUnadmittedTagsBySpecifyingTheAdmittedOnes(admittedTagsArray,textarea.val()) {
   var previoustextareaval = textarea.val()
   var newtextareaval = '';
   [...]  <<  I donno know what
   textarea.val(newtextareaval):
}

//sumbit
$.each( arrayDetectUnadmittedTagsBySpecifyingTheAdmittedOnes, function( k, v ) {
    alert(v+'is unadmitted');
});
</script>
```

#### Example of scenario using a demonstrative text (requested in comments)

```
<textarea id="dt" onchange="arrayDetectUnadmittedTagsBySpecifyingTheAdmittedOnes();">
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
Book traversal <a href="https://stackoverflow.com">links</a> for Demonstratives.
<p>Do you need to improve your English grammar?</p>
Join thousands of learners from around the world who are improving....


A demonstrative <span>pronoun</span> is a pronoun that is used to point to something specific within a sentence.
These pronouns can indicate items in space or time.

</body>
</html>
</textarea>
```

Now, listen, because `admittedTagsArray` does not contains the `span` tag:

`$.inArray('span',admittedTagsArray) == -1`

but also `html`, `body`,`head` append a button over textarea like this

```
<button type="button" onclick="buttonClickedRemoveUnadmittedTagsBySpecifyingTheAdmittedOnes();">Remove tags</button>
```

that if clicked shoud gives the result:

```
<textarea id="dt" onchange="arrayDetectUnadmittedTagsBySpecifyingTheAdmittedOnes();">
Book traversal <a href="https://stackoverflow.com">links</a> for Demonstratives.
<p>Do you need to improve your English grammar?</p>
Join thousands of learners from around the world who are improving....


A demonstrative pronoun is a pronoun that is used to point to something specific within a sentence.
These pronouns can indicate items in space or time.

</textarea>
```

---

Or, that you know there's a tool that does this?

### To selecting tags for preview stackoverflow.com uses the "homemade" function found in edit page code, but it's fool.

```
(() => {
    var e = {
            52830: (e, t, r) => {
                e.exports = function e(t, r, n) {
                    function s(i, a) {
                        if (!r[i]) {
                            if (!t[i]) {
                                if (o) return o(i, !0);
                                var c = new Error("Cannot find module '" + i + "'");
                                throw c.code = "MODULE_NOT_FOUND", c
                            }
                            var l = r[i] = {
                                exports: {}
                            };
                            t[i][0].call(l.exports, (function(e) {
                                return s(t[i][1][e] || e)
                            }), l, l.exports, e, t, r, n)
                        }
                        return r[i].exports
                    }
                    for (var o = void 0, i = 0; i < n.length; i++) s(n[i]);
                    return s
                }({
                    1: [function(e, t, r) {
                        "use strict";
                        t.exports = e("entities/lib/maps/entities.json")
                    }, {
                        "entities/lib/maps/entities.json": 52
                    }],
                    2: [function(e, t, r) {
                        "use strict";
                        t.exports = ["address", "article", "aside", "base", "basefont", "blockquote", "body", "caption", "center", "col", "colgroup", "dd", "details", "dialog", "dir", "div", "dl", "dt", "fieldset", "figcaption", "figure", "footer", "form", "frame", "frameset", "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6", "head", "header", "hr", "html", "iframe", "legend", "li", "link", "main", "menu", "menuitem", "meta", "nav", "noframes", "ol", "optgroup", "option", "p", "param", "section", "source", "summary", "table", "tbody", "td", "tfoot", "th", "thead", "title", "tr", "track", "ul"]
                    }, {}],
                    3: [function(e, t, r) {
                        "use strict";
                        var n = "<[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9\\-]*(?:\\s+[a-zA-Z_:][a-zA-Z0-9:._-]*(?:\\s*=\\s*(?:[^\"'=<>`\\x00-\\x20]+|'[^']*'|\"[^\"]*\"))?)*\\s*\\/?>",
                            s = "<\\/[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9\\-]*\\s*>",
                            o = new RegExp("^(?:" + n + "|" + s + "|\x3c!----\x3e|\x3c!--(?:-?[^>-])(?:-?[^-])*--\x3e|<[?].*?[?]>|<![A-Z]+\\s+[^>]*>|<!\\[CDATA\\[[\\s\\S]*?\\]\\]>)"),
                            i = new RegExp("^(?:" + n + "|" + s + ")");
                        t.exports.HTML_TAG_RE = o, t.exports.HTML_OPEN_CLOSE_TAG_RE = i
                    }, {}],
                    4: [function(e, t, r) {
                        "use strict";
                        var n = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;

                        function s(e, t) {
                            return n.call(e, t)
                        }

                        function o(e) {
                            return !(e >= 55296 && e <= 57343 || e >= 64976 && e <= 65007 || 65535 == (65535 & e) || 65534 == (65535 & e) || e >= 0 && e <= 8 || 11 === e || e >= 14 && e <= 31 || e >= 127 && e <= 159 || e > 1114111)
                        }

                        function i(e) {
                            if (e > 65535) {
                                var t = 55296 + ((e -= 65536) >> 10),
                                    r = 56320 + (1023 & e);
                                return String.fromCharCode(t, r)
                            }
                            return String.fromCharCode(e)
                        }
                        var a = /\\([!"#$%&'()*+,\-.\/:;<=>?@[\\\]^_`{|}~])/g,
                            c = new RegExp(a.source + "|" + /&([a-z#][a-z0-9]{1,31});/gi.source, "gi"),
                            l = /^#((?:x[a-f0-9]{1,8}|[0-9]{1,8}))/i,
                            u = e("./entities"),
                            p = /[&<>"]/,
                            h = /[&<>"]/g,
                            f = {
                                "&": "&amp;",
                                "<": "&lt;",
                                ">": "&gt;",
                                '"': "&quot;"
                            };

                        function d(e) {
                            return f[e]
                        }
                        var m = /[.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-]/g,
                            _ = e("uc.micro/categories/P/regex");
                        r.lib = {}, r.lib.mdurl = e("mdurl"), r.lib.ucmicro = e("uc.micro"), r.assign = function(e) {
                            return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1).forEach((function(t) {
                                if (t) {
                                    if ("object" != typeof t) throw new TypeError(t + "must be object");
                                    Object.keys(t).forEach((function(r) {
                                        e[r] = t[r]
                                    }))
                                }
                            })), e
                        }, r.isString = function(e) {
                            return "[object String]" === function(e) {
                                return Object.prototype.toString.call(e)
                            }(e)
                        }, r.has = s, r.unescapeMd = function(e) {
                            return e.indexOf("\\") < 0 ? e : e.replace(a, "$1")
                        }, r.unescapeAll = function(e) {
                            return e.indexOf("\\") < 0 && e.indexOf("&") < 0 ? e : e.replace(c, (function(e, t, r) {
                                return t || function(e, t) {
                                    var r = 0;
                                    return s(u, t) ? u[t] : 35 === t.charCodeAt(0) && l.test(t) && o(r = "x" === t[1].toLowerCase() ? parseInt(t.slice(2), 16) : parseInt(t.slice(1), 10)) ? i(r) : e
                                }(e, r)
                            }))
                        }, r.isValidEntityCode = o, r.fromCodePoint = i, r.escapeHtml = function(e) {
                            return p.test(e) ? e.replace(h, d) : e
                        }, r.arrayReplaceAt = function(e, t, r) {
                            return [].concat(e.slice(0, t), r, e.slice(t + 1))
                        }, r.isSpace = function(e) {
                            switch (e) {
                                case 9:
                                case 32:
                                    return !0
                            }
                            return !1
                        }, r.isWhiteSpace = function(e) {
                            if (e >= 8192 && e <= 8202) return !0;
                            switch (e) {
                                case 9:
                                case 10:
                                case 11:
                                case 12:
                                case 13:
                                case 32:
                                case 160:
                                case 5760:
                                case 8239:
                                case 8287:
                                case 12288:
                                    return !0
                            }
                            return !1
                        }, r.isMdAsciiPunct = function(e) {
                            switch (e) {
                                case 33:
                                case 34:
                                case 35:
                                case 36:
                                case 37:
                                case 38:
                                case 39:
                                case 40:
                                case 41:
                                case 42:
                                case 43:
                                case 44:
                                case 45:
                                case 46:
                                case 47:
                                case 58:
                                case 59:
                                case 60:
                                case 61:
                                case 62:
                                case 63:
                                case 64:
                                case 91:
                                case 92:
                                case 93:
                                case 94:
                                case 95:
                                case 96:
                                case 123:
                                case 124:
                                case 125:
                                case 126:
                                    return !0;
                                default:
                                    return !1
                            }
                        }, r.isPunctChar = function(e) {
                            return _.test(e)
                        }, r.escapeRE = function(e) {
                            return e.replace(m, "\\$&")
                        }, r.normalizeReference = function(e) {
                            return e = e.trim().replace(/\s+/g, " "), "á¹¾" === "áºž".toLowerCase() && (e = e.replace(/\u1e9e/g, "ÃŸ")), e.toLowerCase().toUpperCase()
                        }
                    }, {
                        "./entities": 1,
                        mdurl: 58,
                        "uc.micro": 65,
                        "uc.micro/categories/P/regex": 63
                    }],
                    5: [function(e, t, r) {
                        "use strict";
                        r.parseLinkLabel = e("./parse_link_label"), r.parseLinkDestination = e("./parse_link_destination"), r.parseLinkTitle = e("./parse_link_title")
                    }, {
                        "./parse_link_destination": 6,
                        "./parse_link_label": 7,
                        "./parse_link_title": 8
                    }],
                    6: [function(e, t, r) {
                        "use strict";
                        var n = e("../common/utils").unescapeAll;
                        t.exports = function(e, t, r) {
                            var s, o, i = t,
                                a = {
                                    ok: !1,
                                    pos: 0,
                                    lines: 0,
                                    str: ""
                                };
                            if (60 === e.charCodeAt(t)) {
                                for (t++; t < r;) {
                                    if (10 === (s = e.charCodeAt(t))) return a;
                                    if (62 === s) return a.pos = t + 1, a.str = n(e.slice(i + 1, t)), a.ok = !0, a;
                                    92 === s && t + 1 < r ? t += 2 : t++
                                }
                                return a
                            }
                            for (o = 0; t < r && 32 !== (s = e.charCodeAt(t)) && !(s < 32 || 127 === s);)
                                if (92 === s && t + 1 < r) t += 2;
                                else {
                                    if (40 === s && o++, 41 === s) {
                                        if (0 === o) break;
                                        o--
                                    }
                                    t++
                                } return i === t || 0 !== o || (a.str = n(e.slice(i, t)), a.lines = 0, a.pos = t, a.ok = !0), a
                        }
                    }, {
})();

....
```

I can't write it all in the post. It's too much long. It's incomprensible. Uses numerics calling for functions name.

You can find it if you want here https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/markdown-it-loader.en.js?v=5818ef89ff9d

It's excellent. Removes from preview selectors that can upsetting the html code.

I'm writing about `<style>* { height: 0px; }</style>` or something like `<style>body { background-color: tomato; }</style>`

So exists a tool that do something like this for preview?

TNX

So, there's a tool that do a selection of tags for preview (client side) in JQuery.

Comment: @ths "what this question" this sentence is incomprehensible from my vocabulary. "What do you want to achieve?" it's in title >> Detect unadmitted tags by specifying the admitted ones in a textarea using JQuery or Javascript and if a button it's clicked remove it "What does unadmitted tags mean in your context?" Each tag in textarea except for the admitted ones

Comment: @ths "Can you provide an example or a scenario that could help us to understand the issue" wait a minute I add it in the question

Comment: @ths "ok cool, please comment here so i can see the updated question." I'm not so cool like you said, but your scenario it's ready to party 

Comment: @ths "By the way, I didn't say you're cool. Just to clarify." Tnx maaan. Grateful 4 this  